# How to bundle PHP rows into collapsible form? (Elemental access to multidimensional array using next())

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, multidimensional-array

I've got something like this:

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        switch ($row["card_id"]) {
            case 0:
                include 'card_0.php';
                break;
            case 1:
                include 'card_1.php';
                break;
            case 2:
                include 'card_2.php';
                break;
            case 3:
                include 'card_3.php';
                break;
        }
}
```

In the case that `card_id` is `1` I want to detect whether the next row's card_id is the same, and whether the next next row's card_id is the same and so on until I have them all and then put their associated field elements into an unordered list---as a bootstrap collapsible object. The whole idea here is that I don't want `card_1` events stacked right on top of each other. I want them to be collapsible. So, since my events are ordered by date they'll look like this:

```
card_0
card_1
card_1
card_1
card_3
card_2
card_2
card_1
card_1
card_1
card_1
```

I want it to look like this instead:

```
card_0
CARD_1<--clickable collapsible
card_3
card_2
card_2
CARD_1<--clickable collapsible
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
while( $i == TRUE ) {
    while( current($row["card_id"]) == next($row["card_id"]) ) {
        $pea_pod[] = $row["field"];
        }
    $i = FALSE;
}
```

Would that work?

Comment: I was trying to use next($row), but $row is an array of arrays, so...

Comment: The card_1's are detracting from the importance of the other cards...

Comment: Error: `current() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given`

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before, a neat trick I used was to use the card as the item in the arrays ID ie:

```
array[card_1][$i]
```

then count array[card_1]

EDIT:

not $i use the default:

```
array[card_1][]
```